# What is the shortest way to write a condition for filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-6, higher-order-functions

What would be the shortest way to write a condition for javascript `filter` method?

I know this way: `array.filter(elem => elem > 2);` But I know you can write this even without specifying an `elem` parameter.

`array.filter($1 > 2)` or like so.

Comment: it depends, what do you mean with shortest? bytewise, or just a buit-in callback, like `Number`?

Comment: I mean something like "array.filter($1 > 2)". I've seen it somewhere.

Comment: I'm having a feeling that people downvote questions because they can't answer it or because there's no answer. "No" is still an answer.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides i have rather a feeling this should have been posted on stackexchange code golf. There is no real coding problem here

Comment: I'm guessing the OP means terse, not unreadable. Granted, the line between the 2 might be subjective.

Comment: @АннаКочешкова, where have you seen such condition? it looks like aprt of a sreadsheet?

Comment: just for info, a minifier only removes spaces and the semicolon, which gives `array.filter(a=>a>2)`

Answer (score 1):

`array.filter(c)` could be the smallest conditon for filter.

Here `c` is a named function which will be the callback for filter.

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];

c = e => e > 2;

var x = array.filter(c);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: To be honest, if `c` is going to be reused, then it makes sense. Else I'd prefer OP's code. Also, though opinionated comment, too much brevity destroys readability.

Comment: @Rajesh I agree with you. But the whole point of the question is to make the callback shorter..

Answer (score 1):

Trying a one-line code, the shortest one would be:

```
array.filter(e => e > 2);
```

The filter() method

```
var newArray = arr.filter(callback[, thisArg])
```

expects a *callback function*. It's the shortest way to define a test function.

**NOTE**: In `swift` code, there is a way to do that in a simple expression:

```
array.filter { $0 > 2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest would be

```
array.filter(c); // c for "condition"
```

And that would require you to have a method `c` defined elsewhere

```
function c(elem){
   return elem > 2;
}
// or var c = elem => elem > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The easyest way is to store your function in a variable and pass it to `filter`

```
const greaterThan2 = x =>
    x > 2

arrays.filter(greaterThan2)
```

There are more benefits that only a shorter version:

- easyer to test
- reusable
- readable

## More than one argument

If you have a function that takes more than one arguments you can [`currying`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) it. An example with `greater` again:

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const greater = b => a =>
  a > b

console.log(
  numbers.filter(greater(2))
)
```

To make the code more spoken you could asign `equal` to variable like `greaterThan2 = equal(2)`

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const greater = b => a =>
  a > b

const greaterThan2 = 
  greater(2)

console.log(
  numbers.filter(greaterThan2)
)
```